# udev rule with {serial} for ttyUSB not working

Tags: usb, tty, udev

I am using Ubuntu 17.10 along a tty-to-USB adapter (adding more in future), thus intending to create a unique udev identifyier to the adapter.

I did **lsusb**:

```
Bus 007 Device 002: ID 067b:2303 Prolific Technology, Inc. PL2303 Serial Port
```

**udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0 | grep '{serial}' | head -n1** leads to

```
ATTRS{serial}=="**0000:00:16.0**"
```

thus I did **sudo vi /etc/udev/rules.d/99-usb-serial.rules**

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303", ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:16.0", SYMLINK+="ttyUSBComfoAir"
```

after a **sudo udevadm control --reload-rules && sudo udevadm trigger** I expected some /dev/ttyUSB...., but a **ll /dev/ttyUSB*** leads to

```
crw-rw---- 1 root dialout 188, 0 Nov 20 18:04 /dev/ttyUSB0
```

ONLY if I omit **ATTRS{serial}** it works.....

ANY IDEA?? - as adding more of these adapters will require the serial number to differentiate the adapters...

Hi!
as I am not so clear what the relevant parts are: I am adding the complete output...

```
  looking at device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0/ttyUSB0/tty/ttyUSB0':
    KERNEL=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEM=="tty"
    DRIVER==""

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0/ttyUSB0':
    KERNELS=="ttyUSB0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb-serial"
    DRIVERS=="pl2303"
    ATTRS{port_number}=="0"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7/7-1/7-1:1.0':
    KERNELS=="7-1:1.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="pl2303"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{bAlternateSetting}==" 0"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceClass}=="ff"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceNumber}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bInterfaceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bNumEndpoints}=="03"
    ATTRS{supports_autosuspend}=="1"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7/7-1':
    KERNELS=="7-1"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="100mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0400"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="80"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="7"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="2"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="1"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Prolific Technology Inc. "
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="0"
    ATTRS{product}=="USB-Serial Controller D"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="258959"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7':
    KERNELS=="usb7"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="usb"
    DRIVERS=="usb"
    ATTRS{authorized}=="1"
    ATTRS{authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{avoid_reset_quirk}=="0"
    ATTRS{bConfigurationValue}=="1"
    ATTRS{bDeviceClass}=="09"
    ATTRS{bDeviceProtocol}=="00"
    ATTRS{bDeviceSubClass}=="00"
    ATTRS{bMaxPacketSize0}=="64"
    ATTRS{bMaxPower}=="0mA"
    ATTRS{bNumConfigurations}=="1"
    ATTRS{bNumInterfaces}==" 1"
    ATTRS{bcdDevice}=="0413"
    ATTRS{bmAttributes}=="e0"
    ATTRS{busnum}=="7"
    ATTRS{configuration}==""
    ATTRS{devnum}=="1"
    ATTRS{devpath}=="0"
    ATTRS{idProduct}=="0001"
    ATTRS{idVendor}=="1d6b"
    ATTRS{interface_authorized_default}=="1"
    ATTRS{ltm_capable}=="no"
    ATTRS{manufacturer}=="Linux 4.13.0-16-generic ohci_hcd"
    ATTRS{maxchild}=="4"
    ATTRS{product}=="OHCI PCI host controller"
    ATTRS{quirks}=="0x0"
    ATTRS{removable}=="unknown"
    ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:16.0"
    ATTRS{speed}=="12"
    ATTRS{urbnum}=="36"
    ATTRS{version}==" 1.10"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0':
    KERNELS=="0000:00:16.0"
    SUBSYSTEMS=="pci"
    DRIVERS=="ohci-pci"
    ATTRS{broken_parity_status}=="0"
    ATTRS{class}=="0x0c0310"
    ATTRS{consistent_dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{d3cold_allowed}=="0"
    ATTRS{device}=="0x4397"
    ATTRS{dma_mask_bits}=="32"
    ATTRS{driver_override}=="(null)"
    ATTRS{enable}=="1"
    ATTRS{irq}=="18"
    ATTRS{local_cpulist}=="0-1"
    ATTRS{local_cpus}=="3"
    ATTRS{msi_bus}=="1"
    ATTRS{numa_node}=="-1"
    ATTRS{revision}=="0x00"
    ATTRS{subsystem_device}=="0x8496"
    ATTRS{subsystem_vendor}=="0x1043"
    ATTRS{vendor}=="0x1002"

  looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00':
    KERNELS=="pci0000:00"
    SUBSYSTEMS==""
    DRIVERS==""
```

Comment: udevad shows some asterisks? or is it a formatting problem?

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the relevant section(s) of the complete `udevadm info -a -n /dev/ttyUSB0` please? IIRC it's important for the `ATTRS` all to belong to the same parent: see for example [Finding suitable information from sysfs](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html#udevinfo) in [Writing udev rules](http://www.reactivated.net/writing_udev_rules.html)

Comment: @pim: I am not sure how I can make a mistake in a single line.... it looks like the one above..... is there something suspicious?

Comment: @steeldriver: I added the complete output above....    looks like I am correctly using the serial-ID from the parent ..... not clear how to solve the issue!

Comment: Hmm... in that case I'm stumped - sorry

Comment: @steeldriver: thanks for trying! maybe we get it done in a way

Answer (score 3):

As far as I know you can only combine the information of one particular child with the parent. In your line

```
SUBSYSTEM=="tty", ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303", ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:16.0", SYMLINK+="ttyUSBComfoAir"
```

you combine information from this child

```
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7/7-1':
```

AND this child

```
looking at parent device '/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:16.0/usb7':`
```

If you look at the former, there's no ATTRS(serial) included and if you look at the latter there's no ATTRS(idVendor/idProduct) included.

Answer (score 1):

- Udev rules don't support mixing conditions from multiple parent nodes.

  1. the leaf/target node: `SUBSYSTEM=="tty"`
  2. a parent node: `ATTRS{idVendor}=="067b", ATTRS{idProduct}=="2303"`
  3. another parent node: `ATTRS{serial}=="0000:00:16.0"`
- This is a known issue with many rs232 adapters which have no serial. Usually, users choose fixed USB port for specific adapter and set a udev rule for that specific port.
- Other option, Some PL2303 chips could be reprogrammed with custom serial and even vid/pid. Tool is provided for free but it needs an adapter that provide the programming voltage 6.5v to the chip (normal mode 5v).